# Make labels of ChartJS radar in a few rows

Tags: charts, chart.js, radar-chart

I create radar chart with ChartJS.

But when I have long labels than ChartJS scale chart and make it smaller.

The question is – can I make label text with ChartJS radar in a two rows? (usual `<br>`,`/n` doesn't work).

Seems like documentation doesn't provide this possibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use custom tooltips to use HTML elements to display the tooltip instead of canvas elements.

There is an example at https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/blob/v1.0.2/samples/pie-customTooltips.html for pie charts that does this.

Comment: Amazing simple answer but great answer. I didn't really used custom tooltips so didn't know. Thanks!